# Calculate $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{n+12}{n^3+5n^2+6n}$.

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, sequences-and-series, analysis, convergence-divergence

I've tried to rewrite $\frac{1}{n^{3}+5n^2+6n}$ as $\frac{1}{6n}-\frac{1}{2(n+2)}+\frac{1}{3(n+3)}$. That only tells me that the series is effectively convergent, because it behaviours like $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\left(\frac{1}{6}-\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{3}\right)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}0=0$. But I don't know how to continue from that, or even if this is the most appropiate way to solve the problem.

I will appreciate any advice. Thanks to all!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We use the partial fraction decomposition of the actual summand, which splits into two telescoping series:
$$\frac{n+12}{n^3+5n^2+6n}=2\left(\frac1n-\frac1{n+2}\right)-3\left(\frac1{n+2}-\frac1{n+3}\right)$$
Thus the sum is
$$2\left(\frac11+\frac12\right)-3\cdot\frac13=2$$

Comment: (+1) Nice (an fast) answer.